# Как в sublimeText - sublimeREPL,передавать в интерпретатор php файлы php

Tags: php, sublime-text

Проблема с плагином для `sublime text` - `sublimeREPL`.

При запуске `Tools\sublimeREPL\PHP` - интерпретатор включается, и  команды там работают.

А вот если передавать файл -  `Tools\sublimeREPL\Eval in REPL` - выдается ошибка

> Cannot find REPL for 'php'.

Название файла `index.php`.

A для `pythona` все работает.

Подскажите как передавать файлы?

Answer (score 0):

Всё просто:
Открываешь "Tools - Build System - New Build System..."
Удаляешь всё и вставляешь 3 строки

```
{
    "cmd": ["C:/php/php.exe", "$file"]
}
```

Вместо "C:/php/php.exe" может быть другой путь к компилятору. 
Сохраняешь под именем PHP. 
Теперь открываешь свой PHP файл, выбираешь в "Tools - Build System - PHP" и по нажатию "Ctrl+B" или "Tools - Build" в нижнем окне получаешь выдачу.